# Portable binary file for storing double in C++

Tags: c++, file

Let us consider 2 PC's: PC A which requires 64 bit (8 bytes) to store a double variable and PC B which requires 128 bit (16 bytes) to store a double variable. A binary file is created in using my application on A. The file is copied to B and my program is reading the file. Let us consider the file contains 10 double variables. To illustrate the file contains information like this:

```
8888888888
```

//8 represents 8 bytes

Now when B is reading it will see the data as

```
1616161616
```

//so it reads only 5 variables instead of 10 and that too incorrect values will be stored in these variables.

So my question is, how do you manage the read/write such that the above situations do not occur such that

1. The data can only be stored in a binary file
2. The data is stored by the appication in double[] and it cannot be converted to strings because there are millions of double variables in real life situations and translation time is too much

I tried by reading the data in char * of appropriate length. But when the char * is converted to double by reinterpret_cast the double has garbage value.

Comment: Specify, document and implement a serialization format.

Comment: Use stdfloat.h and float64_t instead of relying on the size of double.

Comment: @cup my application compiler does not have C++11 capability.

Comment: How would you define a 64-bit float on PC B?  Which compiler/OS are you using?

Comment: @cup the C++ standard defines a minmum size for double, but a PC can have more than that size to have more range. I am just trying to tackle such PC's if they exist. I currently dont have such a PC, but just being prepared in case such a PC does exist. I understand that it would not use IEEE 754 standard for the double variable. So I might have to deduce the decimal value from the binary manually. But I dont know how to read such bit level data.

Comment: There is a long double type that exists on some compilers.  On some 32-bit architectures, the long double is 12 bytes.  On some 64-bit architectures, it is 16 bytes.  You could try your experiment on long doubles instead of doubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an existing serialization library such as [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/), or the newer [cap'nproto](http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/cxx.html) (which optimizes for the most common use-case).

Comment: I am using Qt. It has a QDataStream class which serialises the basic C++ data types.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: It is good only until the file is read/written on the same PC. It does not have portability. See the example I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Ah. protobuf and cap'nproto are both designed to be portable.